# jQuery - Change class in HTML through Javascript by if/else if

Tags: javascript, validation, input, label, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap validation form which is working perfectly and also changing the inputField colour on `error` & `success`.

The problem is, I want to change the `text-color` and `border-color` of **Label**. I have tried various JavaScript code but no one works for me as I am not familiar with javascript.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" class="form-horizontal form-bordered storyForm" novalidate>

<div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group" id="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="control-label" id="label" for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="control-label" id="label" for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="offset-sm-3 col-md-9">
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Submit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
form.storyForm label{
  padding: 0px 25px;
  /* background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15); */
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid white !important;
  top: 1px;
  position: relative;
}
form.storyForm label.error{
  padding: 0px 25px;
  /* background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15); */
  color: #ef5350;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #ef5350;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white !important;
  top: 1px;
  position: relative;
}
form.storyForm label.validate{
  padding: 0px 25px;
  /* background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15); */
  color: #26dad2;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #26dad2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white !important;
  top: 1px;
  position: relative;
}
```

The **javascript** code which I'm trying to add/remove the class

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        if ($("#form-group").hasClass("error")) {
            $("#label").addClass("error");
        } else if ($("#form-group").hasClass("validate")) {
            $("#label").removeClass("error");
            $("#label").addClass("validate");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I also checked throught `class` but it was also not working for me

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#submit").click(function() {
    if ($(".form-group").hasClass("error")) {
        $(".control-label").addClass("error");
    } else if ($("#form-group").hasClass("validate")) {
        $(".control-label").removeClass("error");
        $(".control-label").addClass("validate");
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: your Id's are not unique, id `label ` and id `form-group` are repeating
Id should be unique, since it is identifier, if you want to classify something use class

Comment: I had also used `Class` as well as `Tag`

Comment: First of all you should never use the same id twice in your document,
Second is that you need to fix your jquery selectors after that,
Third, the chances that your js function will do what you want is pretty low, since there is no function at least visible for us which is adding class `validate` or `error` to the elements for the very first time, so both if and else if statements are going to be always false....

Answer (score 0):

ID selectors will only return the *FIRST* element with a matching ID on the page when working in javascript. Here's a simple codepen demonstrating this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYoqZP

Your sizzle selectors should definitely not be an ID selector: `$('#xxxxxxx')`. You should either change `$('#label')` to just be an element selector: `$('label')` or select the class `$('.control-label')`.
You also are using an ID selector for `form-group` which will also only return the first element with that ID, and therefore prevent your click handler from having an effect on the 2nd, 3rd, ... nth form groups.

With your supplied sample, there isn't anything explaining how you are validating your forms, or adding the error classes you are looking up in the first place. So what is happening right now is you are extending the submit button's functionality to submit the form *and* adjust classes. The problem is, when the form submits nothing will happen as you don't have an action and you don't do anything with your data once the user clicks submit.

If you added an `error` class to your form groups and clicked submit, you'd see your changed take effect, but you simply need more code for processing your form for any of this to really do anything.

Comment: All the selectors are fine. He **has** `id` tags... Your answer isn't the right one.

Comment: ID selectors will only return the *FIRST* element with a matching ID on the page when working in javascript. Here's a simple codepen demonstrating this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYoqZP

Comment: Updated my answer to provide more info around how to make this work as a proof of concept. If you are handling the form in a way you haven't shown here, then great! but from what you've supplied this just can't work because nothing is adding your initial error classes period

Answer (score 0):

You are using `'$'` inside the `JavaScript`, make sure you've included the `JQuery` library. `'$'` is the primary base object (or function) for JQuery. If you are not using `JQuery`, you need to use `JavaScript` methods such as `.getElementById()` or `.querySelector()` and pass your id value as parameters to these methods.

Also, using querySelector is a better way to address this functionality.

Here is the link to [MDN getElementById() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and [MDN querySelector() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

I hope this helps! Good Luck!

Comment: I had added `JQuery` lib v3.2.0. And I had also tried `.getElementById()` it was also not working.